# "Almost" vertex coloring

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

The following concept arose when studying some properties of a real world computer network.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph. If $v\in V$ we set $N(v)=\{y\in V:\{v,y\}\in E\}$. Let $Z\neq \emptyset$ be a set. A map $c:V\to Z$ is said to be an "almost coloring" of $G$ if for all $v\in V$ the color of $v$ appears at most once in $N(v)$, that is, mathematically speaking, if $$|c^{-1}(\{c(v)\})\cap N(v)| \leq 1.$$ Let $\chi_a(G)$ denote the smallest integer $n$ such that there is an almost coloring $c:V\to\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

**Question**. If $G,H$ are finite, simple, undirected graphs with $\chi(G)\le \chi(H)$, does this imply that $\chi_a(G)\le\chi_a(H)$?

---

Also, I would be very grateful for a reference in case this concept that I call almost coloring has been studied elsewhere.

Comment: No, take $G=K_{2,1}$, $H=K_{1,1}$.

Comment: @Dominic van der Zypen:  re your reference request: what comes to mind of course, and is at least *similar* in spirit, is the concept of *conflict free coloring*. See e.g. Shakhar Smorodinsky,  [A Survey on Conflict-Free Colorings](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~shakhar/my_papers/reprint.pdf). Please note: I am *not* saying that this were *equivalent*. I did not stop to think about how similar this is. But against the background you gave to your question, it may be helpful to be reminded of this similar concept.

Comment: @PeterHeinig Thanks for this reference, I'll check out conflict-free colorings!

Comment: @FedorPetrov is right, but he has $G$ and $H$ mixed up. What he was pointing out is that $\chi(K_{1,1}) = \chi(K_{2,1})$, but $\chi_a(K_{1,1}) < \chi_a(K_{2,1})$.

Comment: @PeterHeinig I think, $\chi_a(K_{21})=2$, is not it?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Yes, $\chi_a(K_{2,1})=2$.

Comment: @TobiasFritz I think, I did not even mix them up:)

Comment: Thanks @FedorPetrov and Tobias ... could any one of you write an answer?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: of course, sorry, the mix-up was only in my head!

Comment: In the complete graph on an even number of vertices, a maximal matching inspires an almost coloring on the graph, giving a difference in  the two coloring numbers of size about half the number of vertices.  This difference may get much smaller for graphs with fewer edges.  Gerhard "Might Have Graph Parameter Inequality' Paseman, 2017.07.21.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen: in case you really need to know as much as possible about "coloring with defect 1" (as David Wood correctly pointed out it is called), let me mention a relevant reference so new that it is not yet available: the is a talk on the subject coming up: [David Wood of Monash University, Tutorial on defective and clustered graph colouring, scheduled for Monday August 21 between 09:00 and 10:00 MDT](https://www.birs.ca/live)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No for $G=K_{2,1}$ (two edges with common vertex) and $H=K_{1,1}$ (an edge). Both chromatic numbers are equal to 1, and almost chromatic numbers are 2 and 1 respectively.

Answer (score 5):

This is called a "colouring with defect 1". If each vertex is adjacent to at most $d$ vertices of the same colour, then it is a colouring with defect $d$. There is a huge literature on this topic; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_coloring.